# React-redux project not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, styled-components

I am new to redux. I have experience with react context-api. This is my first time using redux. I have all the latest versions installed of redux, react-router, styled-components from their official websites. I have no idea what to do about this error. Please help me get out of this mess.

[This is my Pakage.JSON as well as the error shown in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49B4r.png)

[This is where I used my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VTUl.png)

[This my index.js and appSlice.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmkSF.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a redux issue, but a react hook that is not used in the right place, I think we need more code to understand the problem

Comment: Would you please tell me which files do you want ill provide it. And thanks for help.

Comment: I have added some new images please check them.